# Why does @ not always show the name of the user

Tags: support, comments, comment-replies

I've come across this a few times where I'm trying to reply to a user in a comment, and their nick is say 'Geomettry2', I start typing my answer with @Geo but no name shows up. I can't include their name in my comment. I'm not sure if this is the right place o ask this but yeah. Most of the time when I type @nick, there's that little popup which shows the name I can click on.

Comment: The nickname only shows up when that user commented before you. For example, I can't @<tab> anybody, here. Not even the OP. But when you reply, I can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The nickname only shows up when that user commented before you, *and* they are not the author of the post (at least not until more people have also commented).

For example, I can't @ anybody, in a comment on your question, nor can you @Cerbrus (unless you type it manually), until I comment on this post.

And even then, if just one other user is replying to me, you won’t be able to mention me as I am the author of this answer, and there can’t be any confusion about who you are addressing. In fact, if you tried anyway [the mention is automatically removed again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97098/eeeeek-what-happened-to-my-salutation/97099#97099).