# The mentions doesn't appear in my comments

Tags: support, comments

When I have to answer in comments, I always try to mention people (e.g. @Drumnbass) but when I post the coment, the mention just gets deleted, it doesn't appear at all. An example of what I do is `@Drumnbass you should use a button.`

However, Stack OverFlow doesn't even suggest me any name.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If that is the OP of the post it is not needed and therefor deleted for you...

Comment: Maybe related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275252/why-does-not-always-show-the-name-of-the-user?s=10|0.0000

Comment: These are not the cases, I'm the owner of the posts and I'm never the first commentor.

Comment: The users have already commented? On what browser are you? On which post did you experience that trouble?

Comment: You are using the site in normal view, not in mobile view?

Comment: The users have always already commented. I use Google Chrome. I emperiment that trouble in all my posts (I can't still comment in other posts due to my low reputation). I don't know what you mean by "mobile view", if it's the smartphone view, I'm not, I'm using a PC.

Comment: So how many users are in that conversation?

Comment: @rene It doesn't matter at all, can be 1, 2, 3, 4... it never works. (e.g. I'm trying to use mentions now with your name but I can't).

Comment: Wait, did it work or isn't it a mention?

Comment: I'm the only commenter, there is no reason for mentioning me and that is the reason my name gets deleted

Comment: @rene nope, only the OP's name is deleted.

Comment: huh, I will try it again in another answer with some people. I will comeback with news.

Comment: @ShadowWizard that is strange, I must have misread the dupe...

Comment: @rene it's now showing, but not deleted either. :)

Comment: @Drumnbass you should now have auto complete for both rene and me.